# Swapping map between different dlls

Tags: c++, dictionary, dll, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have two dlls, say A and B. From which one dll B will swap a map from dll A.

The map structure is

```
map<int,vector<clock_t>>* mObj = new map<int,vector<clock_t>>;
```

Here the mObj is in heap memory.  But the key of map and value (vector elements) are in stack memory. As the stack will be out of scope once it comes out of a block. Will the vector elements still exist when i swap the map which is in different Dll(since it is going out of DLL)..?

Actually I can able to get the vector elements from the swapped map from A.dll inside B.dll. How is that possible..? Only the A.dll's program stack memory had that vector elements (only the map object was in heap) , then how come I can access the vector elements from B.dll ?

Comment: "...But the key of map and value (vector elements) are in stack memory." They are? You've not posted a line of code that actually places a keyed value *in* the map. And `std::map` dynamically manages its content regardless.

Comment: The keys are definitely not in "stack memory".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on certain misconceptions, and won't be helpful for future research.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is on the stack.

`map<int,vector<clock_t>>` does not contain any pointer or reference to anything. The `int` keys will be copied to the internal `map` memory. Same for the `vector` inside the `map` and the `clock_t` inside the `vector`.